# Abrir un modal desde un widget

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente inconveniente, tengo un widget boostrap y necesito que al hacer click abra un modal con una grafica de google chart. No funciona hago click y si me abre un alert, pero cuando configuro para que abra el modal no hace nada.  Adjunto código .PD: la grafica funciona tiene una consulta con la que armo el array pero no muestra nada, directamente no se abre el modal

// widget y modal

```
<div class="col-md-4">
        <a href="" class='aLink'">
        <div class="widget-small"  id="getChart"  style="height: 120px;background-color:#ffc107; "><i  class="icon fas fa-truck fa-3x" style="color: white"></i>
          <div class="info" >

            <h4  style="font-size: 15pt; ">SERVICIOS PÚBLICOS</h4>

            <p style="color: #EFE7DD   ; font-size: 18pt"><b>TOTAL=<b><?php echo $servp['se'] ?></b></b></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
      </div>



<div id="modalservicios" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
  

   

     <div class="chart" id="chart_div" style="background-color: #E5E5E5">
    
                </div>

            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
```

// código de JS

```
  <script>
   $(document).ready(function (){
    $('.aLink').on('click', function (e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#modalservicios").modal('show');
    })
})

  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

// Draw the chart and set the chart values
function drawChart()
{
 var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
   ['Tipo','Tipos de móviles '+' '+''+''+'----'+' '+'Cantidad total:'+'  '+'<?php echo $suma ?>'+' '+'móviles', {role: 'annotation'}],
   <?php

for ($x = 1; $x < sizeof($tipos); $x = $x + 1) {

    ?>
     ['<?php echo $tipos[$x]; ?>', <?php echo $cantidad[$x] ?>,<?php echo $cantidad[$x] ?>],
   <?php }?>

   ]);

 var options = {
  title:''
    ,seriesType: 'bars'
    ,series: {1: {type: 'line'}}
    ,legend:{position: 'top', textStyle: {color: 'blue', fontSize: 16}}
    ,backgroundColor: '#E5E5E5'

  ,width:"100%"
  ,height: 450



};

            // Instantiate and draw the chart.
            var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
            chart.draw(data, options);
          }

          $(window).resize(function(){

            drawChart();

          });

</script>
```